# Lattice not working when I move bones

Tags: armature, bones, lattice

I have made a cartoon eye using a lattice. When moving the eye individually, it works with the lattice fine. When I use a bone to move it (here is the tutorial I used https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OItHr4VRP7M&t=4s) the eye stays in an ovular shape and moves that way. How do I fix it so when I rotate the eye, it will follow the lattice? Please help ASAP!!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to put the *Armature* modifier above the *Lattice* so that the *Lattice* works after the *Armature*.